# ClassCastException when filtering a set by another set

Tags: clojure

Here is a code example from [Clojure Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449394701)

```
(defn character
  [name & {:as opts}]
  (ref (merge {:name name :itmes #{} :health 500}
              opts)))

(def smaug (character "Smaug" :health 500 :strength 400 :items (set (range 50))))
(def bilbo (character "Bilbo" :health 100 :strength 100))
(def gandalf (character "Gandalf" :health 75 :mana 750))

(defn loot
  [from to]
  (dosync
    (when-let [item (first (:items @from))]
      (alter to update-in [:items] conj item)
      (alter from update-in [:items] disj item))))
(wait-futures 1
              (while (loot smaug bilbo))
              (while (loot smaug gandalf)))
(map (comp count :items deref) [bilbo gandalf])
(filter (:items @bilbo) (:items @gandalf))
```

Everything works fine until the last line, which brings up an error:

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  clojure.core/filter/fn--4264 (core.clj:2605)
```

Answer (score 3):

The constructor function "character" typos the key for :items as :itmes, making the conj on alter get nil as the initial value. Conjing nil and a value gives you a list -- thus the ClassCastException.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've got a typo in your definition of character - `:itmes` instead of `:items`.

This means that when you loot, you're calling

`(conj nil 0)`, which turns the entry under `:items` into a list of `(0)`. A list doesn't implement `IFn`, hence the error.